# how to define a Set of Set<Int> (formerly how to pass a Set as function parameter in swift?)

Tags: swift, function, parameters, set

I want to pass a `Set<Int>` as a parameter to a function. When I do:

```
let setsOfWinningCells: Set = [ [0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8], [0,3,6], [1,4,7], [2,5,8], [0,4,8], [2,4,6] ]

func isWinner(playerCells: Set<Int>) {
    for winningCells in setsOfWinningCells {
        if playerCells.isSupersetOf(winningCells) {
            // do something    
        }
    }
}
```

compiler complains it `cannot invoke 'isSuperSetOf' with an argument list of type '(NSArray)'`. Using `Set<Int>()` instead of `Set<Int>` also does not work.

Does anyone know the correct syntax? Thanks

**Clarification**:

I mistakenly thought the problem was passing the Set properly to the function but in fact the issue was not defining the Set of Set properly. Apologies for confusion.

Comment: What's `setsOfWinningCells` defined as?

Comment: Hi Hamish, it's a set of Set<Int>. I see what you mean now

Comment: Thanks, Hamish. This is what I need: let setsOfWinningCells: Set<Set<Int>> = [ [0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8], [0,3,6], [1,4,7], [2,5,8], [0,4,8], [2,4,6] ]

Comment: No problem, was just about to post that as an answer ;) Feel free to delete your question, or post your solution as an answer if you feel it could potentially be of use to someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, Hamish, for pointing out what I missed. My issue was not passing the Set incorrectly but rather my `Set` of `Set<Int>` was not defined correctly. My original definition meant it was a `Set` of `Arrays` of `Int`. It should have been:

```
let setsOfWinningCells: Set<Set<Int>> = [ [0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8], [0,3,6], [1,4,7], [2,5,8], [0,4,8], [2,4,6] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

winningCells is NSArray, you should pass a Set for isSupersetOf(_) function

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your answer by providing replacement or example code. If you are unsure of what to do, feel free to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to better define your problem.

### The Group struct

Let's define a struct to represent the concept of a group of `Int(s)`. We also want the struct to be `Hashable`.

```
struct Group: Hashable {
    let values: Set<Int>
    var hashValue: Int { return values.hashValue }
}

func ==(left:Group, right:Group) -> Bool {
    return left.values == right.values
}
```

### Winning Groups

Now lets create a list of winning groups

```
let winningGroups: Set<Group> = [
    Group(values:[0,1,2]),
    Group(values:[3,4,5]),
    Group(values:[6,7,8]),
    Group(values:[0,3,6]),
    Group(values:[1,4,7]),
    Group(values:[2,5,8]),
    Group(values:[0,4,8]),
    Group(values:[2,4,6])
]
```

### Player Groups

Next we have a list of player groups

```
let playerGroups: Set<Group> = [
    Group(values:[4,0,8]),
    Group(values:[2,4,6])
]
```

### Finding the Player Winning Groups (exact match)

Now we want to select all the Groups that are both in `playerGroups` and `winningGroups`.

```
let playerWinningGroups = playerGroups.intersect(winningGroups)
//[Group(values: Set([5, 4, 3])), Group(values: Set([2, 0, 1]))]
```

> As you can ses the order of the `Int(s)` inside the Group is **not** relevant.
>
> E.g. Player has `[4,3,5]` and a winning group is `[3,4,5]`. Even if the values are in different order the group is still added to the result.

### Finding the Player Winning Groups (supersets)

Let's consider this player groups

```
let playerGroups: Set<Group> = [
    Group(values:[4,0,8]),
    Group(values:[2,4,6]),
    Group(values:[6,7,8,9]),
]
```

The third group is a superset of the winning group `[6,7,8,9]`. However the previous solution does not pick this element.

Let's see a solution that returns also supergroups of the winningGroups

```
var res = Set<Group>()
playerGroups.forEach { (playerGroup) in
    if (winningGroups.contains({ (winninGroup) -> Bool in return winninGroup.values.isSubsetOf(playerGroup.values) })) {
        res.insert(playerGroup)
    }
}

print(res) // [Group(values: Set([2, 4, 6])), Group(values: Set([6, 7, 9, 8])), Group(values: Set([4, 0, 8]))]
```